# Changes to PATH variable not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

For the life of me, I can't seem to add my Quartus bin directory to the PATH variable.

To add for all users, I edited /etc/profile by adding the line below as follows: (opening the file with sudo gedit /etc/profile)

```
/home/jaco/altera/14.0/quartus/bin/
```

I close the file, execute . ./etc/profile, after which I execute echo $PATH. This displays the directory I've just added, but when I open another shell and execute echo $PATH again, the directory is gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, turns out adding the same line to ~/.bashrc worked ... Not sure what's the difference, but anyways.

Comment: ~/.bashrc isn't a solution that will work for all users though (Unless you add it to all user's .bashrc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never made changes to `/etc/profile` but I know that env variables, aliases etc can be added to ~/.bashrc. You usually have to start a new shell or run `source ~/.bashrc` after editing your .bashrc file to load the new cahnges.

I think you will have to add it to all users. Also (this helps for future accounts) you can add it in your `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file. That is the skeleton file used when creating new users.